# How to escape an error when accessing a non-existent key with an ordinal number

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, undefined

The result of the code below is Cat and undefined.
*If the key does not exist, the result will be "undefined".

```
   var animals = {"mammals":["Cat","Dog","Cow"]};
   var groupA  = animals.mammals[0];
   var groupB  = animals.birds;
   console.log(groupA );
   console.log(groupB);
```

However, The result of the below code is "error" instead of "undefined".

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

```js
var animals = {
  "mammals": ["Cat", "Dog", "Cow"]
};
var groupA = animals.mammals[0];
var groupB = animals.birds[0];

console.log(groupA);
console.log(groupB);
```

If the key have an ordinal number which doesn't exist, How to get an "undefined" ?

Comment: `.birds;` is undefined since well, it is not defined anywhere and thus an element 0 of undefined `.birds` does not exist so referencing it is an error

Comment: By "escape" do you mean avoid, handle, prevent or really actually "escape" that as in "The `escape()` function computes a new string in which certain characters have been replaced by a hexadecimal escape sequence."

Answer (score 3):

You can use  [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

> The optional **chaining operator** (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

```js
var animals = {
  "mammals": ["Cat", "Dog", "Cow"]
};
var groupA = animals.mammals?.[0];
var groupB = animals.birds?.[0];

console.log(groupA);
console.log(groupB);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to evaluate the attribute first, see below:

```
var animals = {"mammals":["Cat","Dog","Cow"]};
var groupA  = animals.mammals[0];
var groupB  = (animals.birds || [])[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check for the property and explicitly set that value with a ternary:

```js
var animals = {
  "mammals": ["Cat", "Dog", "Cow"]
};
var groupA = animals.mammals ? animals.mammals[0] : undefined;
var groupB = animals.birds ? animals.birds[0] : undefined;

console.log(groupA);
console.log(groupB);
```

Answer (score 2):

In second case:
`birds` itself is undefined on the object animals.
Accesing property of undefined is throwing the error.

It is like doing `undefined[0]`.
Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
var animals = {
  "mammals": ["Cat", "Dog", "Cow"]
};
var groupA = animals.mammals?.[0];
var groupB = animals.birds?.[0];

console.log(groupA);
console.log(groupB);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) blocks to catch exceptions and handle them as needed (surround anything you think might throw errors):

```js
const animals = {
  "mammals": ["Cat", "Dog", "Cow"]
};
let groupA, groupB, groupC;
groupA = animals.mammals[0];
groupB = animals.birds;
try {
  groupC = animals.birds[0];
} catch (error) {
  console.error(
    "'animals.birds' is undefined, so we cannot access property '0'."
  );
}
console.log(groupA);
console.log(groupB);
console.log(groupC);
```